# Would English speakers use "by themselves" here

Tags: grammaticality, spoken-english

I have heard from a friend of mine the statement below:

> The school never forces students to pay their fees; they pay their fees in time **by themselves.**

I am aware of the fact that "**by oneself**" commonly means "**do something without others' help."** But here i am trying to express the "**punctuality**" and "**honesty**" of the students.

Is it how English speakers say this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually, if you use oneself there is no reason you can make it plural.

Answer (score 1):

"by themselves" here can also mean "on their own accord", which basically expresses something like honesty and discipline, or just "without being told by others to do it".

As a native speaker, I **would** say it like your friend did. You can also just get rid of "by", making it "they pay their fees in time themselves".